# How to build Fabric.js for unit tests

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

When running the tests on master code `npm test` works fine,
but when I build Fabric locally (with `node build.js modules=ALL`)
the test breaks with error:

> { [Error: Cannot read property 'navigator' of undefined] message:
>   'Cannot read property \'navigator\' of undefined' }

Even without any changes to the codebase. I guess I'm missing some build flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `node build.js modules=ALL exclude=gestures,cufon,json minifier=uglifyjs`.